# Shell command to know the most requested files on a server

Tags: shell

Is there a ssh command to scan log files and return the top list of the most requested files on a server ?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the most requested files via HTTP in the web server logs?

Comment: What do you mean by "ssh command"? ssh is just a way of connecting to a remote server, it doesn't have any special commands of its own.

Comment: @Michael : Yes, this is exactly it.

Comment: @Barmar : I mean the language we use in a terminal (I thought it was called "SSH")

Comment: It's called "shell".

Comment: :) I manage sites for years but I'm still a noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into utilizing [Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/) for that sort of info.  Most linux builds already come with that pre-installed.  Try `rpm -q webalizer` to see if it's present.

Comment: It's exactly what I need. Thank you another time.